# Show: $\ln (1+x)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\ldots+(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{n}}{n}\right)$

Tags: integration, limits

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_n :[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f_n(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{t^{n}}{1+t} \mathrm{d} t$$

Show:$$\ln (1+x)=\lim _{n \to \infty}\left(x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{n}}{n}\right)$$

Can someone give me a clue how to get started.

Comment: Taylor polynomial with remainder. All you want to show is that the remainder goes to zero.

Comment: Using the given integral you can try long division on your integrand.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: As usual, what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with
$\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
$.

Replacing $x$ by $-x$,
this becomes
$\dfrac{1-(-x)^n}{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-x)^k
$
or
$\dfrac{1-(-1)^n(x)^n}{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^k
$.

Rewrite this as
$\dfrac{1}{1+x}
=\dfrac{(-1)^n(x)^n}{1+x}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^k
$.

Now integrate both sides.

Answer (score -1):

Integrating the both sides of the geometric series from $0$ to $x$
$$\frac{1}{1+t}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} t^k \textrm{ for }|t|<1$$
yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{d t}{1+t} &=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \int_{0}^{x} t^{k} d t \\
\ln(1+x)&=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\frac{(-1)^{k} t^{k+1}}{k+1}\right]_{0}^{x} \\
&=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{k}}{k}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Two things: first, you should integrate the series from $0$ to $x$ and not from $0$ to $1$. Second, you have to justify the interchange of the limit and integral operations.

Comment: First, thank you for fixing my typo.  Second, thank you for your suggestion.